# WPF Databinding only works with explicit ElementName attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

Well I created my first custom control with two dependency properties. One is a `decimal` and the other one has a `CustomType` of my own. So to test it I created a small project with only a window and tried to bind to it by using the Window itself as the data context like this:

```
<somethin:mycontrol MyDependencyProperty="{Binding MyCustomType}"/>
```

Where `MyCustomType`is a Property  in MainWindow.cs and this did not work. So I made a guess and  gave the MainWindow a name and then specified the Element name and it worked like this:

```
<Window x:Class="BC.WPF.TestArea.MainWindow" ... x:Name="MyWindow">
...
      <somethin:mycontrol MyDependencyProperty="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=MyCustomType}"/>

....
</Window>
```

So in my experience the ElementName part shouldn't be necessary but it was working so I was satisfied until I tried using it in an ItemsControl. Then things got really weird. First I tried this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=ObservableMyCustomTypes }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="somehting:CustomType" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Content="{Binding Name }"/>
                <somethin:mycontrol  MyDependencyProperty="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The strange thing here is that `CustomType` has a `Name` property and the Binding to `Content` in the label works but `MyDependencyProperty="{Binding}"` doesn't. I also tried `MyDependencyProperty="{Binding .}"` without success so just out of curiosity I tried putting elements of type `Tuple<CustomType>` in the collection instead and then binded to `Item1` like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=ObservableMyCustomTypes }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="system:Tuple" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Label Content="{Binding Item1.Name }"/>
                <somethin:mycontrol  MyDependencyProperty="{Binding Item1}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the incredible thing is that the Binding in the label to `Item1.Name` works but the other binding doesn't which really puzzles me because now I really don't see what could be wrong with the path but the one with `ElementName=MyWindow` works as expected.

What is going on?

[Here is a link to a zip with the complete test project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=623CC4A099792000!5364&authkey=!AOd0Nmug0fuh2tg&ithint=file%2c.zip) if you are curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you break `DataContext` inheritance in your control by setting `DataContext = this;` in the constructor of your `PercentageOrFixControl`, so the expression

```
PercentageOrFixed="{Binding }"
```

is returning the control itself and not the `PercentageOrFixed` item that is in the collection. The data context for the label is the item of the collection and that's why it finds the `Name` property.

After removing the setter for data context from constructor, inner bindings in the control break since they look for properties on the control. Add

```
, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}
```

to the end of all bindings. For example, the `IsChecked` property of the first `RadioButton` should look like this:

```
IsChecked="{Binding UseFix, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

### Edit

For testing, I removed use of `Tuple` as it's not needed, so the collection is defined as `ObservableCollection<PercentageOrFixed>`

Comment: Thank you I just saw the Console output off the  App and this gave me a hint:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Item1' property not found on 'object' ''PercentageOrFixControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Item1; DataItem='PercentageOrFixControl' (Name=''); target element is 'PercentageOrFixControl' (Name=''); target property is 'PercentageOrFixed' (type 'PercentageOrFixed')

But you answer makes it way clearer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Rather than removing the DataContext = this entirely, it can just be changed to set the DataContext of a root Panel by Name to get both the external bindings and not need the RelativeSource added to everything inside.